# == operator for enum's in Solidity

Tags: solidity

I can't get comparisons (==) of enum types compiling. The following example

```
contract Card
{
    enum Suit {Heart, Diamond, Shape, Club, Jocker}
    Suit public suit;

    enum Rank {Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King, Ace, Jocker}
    Rank public rank;

    function equal(Card card) returns (bool)
    {
        return suit == card.suit && rank == card.rank;
    }
}
```

has the following compile errors

```
Card.sol:11:16: Error: Operator == not compatible with types enum Suit and function () returns (enum Suit)
        return suit == card.suit && rank == card.rank;
               ^---------------^
Card.sol:11:37: Error: Operator == not compatible with types enum Rank and function () returns (enum Rank)
        return suit == card.suit && rank == card.rank;
```

Any ideas on how variables of an enum type can be compared?

Thanks
Nick

Comment: I believe `card.suit` is a function, while `card.suit()` should be the enum.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks, Karl Floersch. card.suit() does return the enum. The following code now compiles

```
contract Card
{
    enum Suit {Heart, Diamond, Shape, Club, Jocker}
    Suit public suit;

    enum Rank {Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King, Ace, Jocker}
    Rank public rank;

    function equal(Card card) returns (bool)
    {
        return suit == card.suit() && rank == card.rank();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you need the stringUtils.sol library which gives you access to comparing strings.

```
/// @dev Compares two strings and returns true iff they are equal.
    function equal(string _a, string _b) returns (bool) {
        return compare(_a, _b) == 0;
    }
```

Comment: how can I convert enum values to string

Comment: @SwapnilKumbhar Please ask in a new question.